# How to store data in firebase without typing the key values again and again?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Currently I'm making a firebase database. I'm new to firebase. When inserting data, we have to type key- value pairs right? But I have some data which require the same key values for the whole table. Like "name", "city" etc.

How can I save those key values in firebase, so that for every time a new record is inserting I don't have to type the key values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no shortcuts for entering data in the console.  It sounds like you should probably write a program to help make it easier to enter data.